# Mapping the img src to other domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to move all the picture, css file to another server,
then let all the img tag src (relative path) point to that server's domain.

E.g., original:

```
<i><img src= "/Content/picture.png" /></i>
```

What I want:

```
<img src="ServerDomain/Content/picture.png" />
```

---

I have tried this jQuery:

```
function Mapping() {
   $('img').each(function() {
       $(this).attr('src', 'ServerDomain' + $(this).attr('src'));
   });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
     Mapping();
});
```

---

but some img tags generated by javascript are not working.

(By the way, the ServerDomain is setting in web.config (get by ajax))

Does it have other solution to solve it?

Comment: `$(this).attr('src', '@Url.Content("~")' + $(this).attr('src'));` . use this. may this helps.

Comment: some tags? maby you have diffetent src on tags that's not working? Show dore examples please

Comment: It would really help if you inspect a non-working <img /> element after page load to see what 'src' value you actually got. Also, I didn't understand how exactly can you get an AppSetting from web.config using an AJAX get request?

Comment: If this move is permanent, I would suggest using Find and Replace and hard-code the images to the new location. This will save you execution time on the client, and avoid unnecessary code.

Comment: @KhalidT. I have a GetDomainController and GetDomainAction in it, and
I get the AppSetting from web.config in this action. In fact, ajax is get domain from /GetDomain/GetDomainAction. Sorry, I didn't descript it clearly above.

Comment: @Gary: In that case, your AJAX call should be placed inside the $(document).ready event handler and the Mapping function should called inside the $.ajax().done callback.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your code runs after the JavaScript that generates the img tags.

So, either move your code after the other code, or call the Mapping function after it

Answer (score 0):

I produce an example working properly on my local that may help you. I don't know your logic that generates the image on the page, so i made a simple one:

```
 <script>
    /* some logic that retrieve the image from somewhere else  - javascript produce image */
    function GetMyPicture() {
        return "28141835294_99d18fa033_z";
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var src = GetMyPicture() + ".jpg";
        $("#my").attr('src', src);
    });

</script>

<script>

    var domain = "https://c7.staticflickr.com/9/8597/";

    function Mapping() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', domain + $(this).attr('src'));
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Mapping();
    });

</script> 

<body>
   <img id="my" src="">
</body>
```